# Define custom paths for some classes when using PSR-4 composer autoload

Tags: php, woocommerce, composer-php

I'm using Composer to autoload,but some classes do not adhere to the namespace structure as they have to exist in the global namespace. What's the best way to do that?I could specify them in the "files" section, but they would eb loaded on every request.
I have class Wc_Product_Whatwever that's inside includes/xxx but must reamin in the global namespace for WooCommerce to work

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "XXX\\Theme\\": "includes/XXX"
    },
    "files": [
        "includes/template-tags/navigation.php",
        "includes/template-tags/styleguide.php"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classmap` autoloading:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XXX\\Theme\\": "includes/XXX"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "includes/template-tags/"
        ]
    }
}
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap.